# How does SOA achieve high availability, service upgrade and ACID transactions?

Tags: transactions, upgrade, soa

How are the below 3 most desirable architecture characteristics achieved in SOA:

1. High availability
2. Online service upgrades
3. ACID transactions

Pointers to any SOA product documentation regarding the above would be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue with you on which characteristics are most desirable when considering a services oriented architecture, but anyhow :)

1. High Availability is usually obtained by having several instances of services running simultaneously. If one, or more, service instances fail requests can still be serviced by the other instances.
2. Online service upgrades can be made by upgrading individual service instances while requests are serviced by other instances (see above). There are some cases where this will not be possible though.
3. ACID transactions are inherently difficult to achieve well in a distributed transactions. See the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) for a resoning around this.